# How should I run multiple scripts; create a big script to execute classes/functions in order or call the next function until end result is returned?

Tags: python, design-patterns

I have built a number of Python scripts (`classes` + `functions`) relating to poker, where the order that they run does matters.

I am at the final stage where I am considering whether to create a separate script that inherits from all the classes then calls each function in the correct order (though I imagine this would be a very long script, and it doesn't seem that practical).

Or should I incorporate the ordering of execution in the function themselves, so one function would call the next function and then the next function, and so on. So all I would do is to execute the first function, and then like dominoes they will continue executing the next functions until the end result is `returned`.

Comment: You gave us way to little info to tell for sure, but usually you want control of the application flow in one place. Which translates to calling each function separetely, getting the data you are interested in, and passing relevant data to the next one and so on.

Comment: What other information would be useful? As it's a lot of scripts and code I can't quite share it here